# Binary XML file line #13: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

I am noticing an issue with inflating the initial fragment via XML. What I am noticing is that the `onPause()`, `onDestroy()` lifecycle methods are not being called properly. If I replace this fragment, everything works fine. The issue is only when the app is first launched and the initial fragment is inflated via XML. To avoid this conflict I tried to launch the initial fragment programmatically but I keep receiving an `inflating class error`.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com..tap/com.example.tap.activity.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class fragment
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3254)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3350)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:222)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1795)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7237)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class fragment
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:551)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:143)
    at com.example.tap.activity.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:69)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6876)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3207)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3350) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:222) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1795) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7237) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class fragment
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:794)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:716)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:847)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:810)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:527)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:143) 
    at com.example.tap.activity.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:69) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6876) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1135) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3207) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3350) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:222) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1795) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7237) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.lang.VMClassLoader.findLoadedClass(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findLoadedClass(ClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:499)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.isSupportFragmentClass(Fragment.java:469)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2384)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:120)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:378)
    at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.onCreateView(BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.java:33)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:77)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:766)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:716) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:847) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:810) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:527) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:143) 
    at com.example.tap.activity.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:69) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6876) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1135) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3207) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3350) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:222) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1795) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7237) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Here is how I am inflating my initial fragment via XML. In the Activity that is first launched, I added this segment of code to its layout

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/frag_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.example.fragments.MainFragment" />
```

When I change fragments, such as clicking on a tab I replace the fragment using the following method

```
public void addFragmentReplace(int containerId, Fragment fragment) {
    // check if the fragment has been added already
    Fragment temp = mFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(fragment.getClass().getSimpleName());
    if (!Utils.checkIfNull(temp) && temp.isAdded()) {
        return;
    }

    // replace fragment and transition with animation
    try {
        if (!Utils.isStringEmpty(getTopFragment().getTag()) && getTopFragment().isAdded()) {
            // pop back stack
            popBackStack();
        }
        mFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(containerId, fragment,
                fragment.getClass().getSimpleName()).addToBackStack(null).commit();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        mFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(containerId, fragment,
                fragment.getClass().getSimpleName()).addToBackStack(null)
                .commitAllowingStateLoss(); // used as last resort
    }
}
```

After changing tabs the fragment lifecycle works perfectly. Even when returning to the original tab. But how do I get the lifecycle to work initially when the fragment is inflated via XML or how can I remove the class property from XML and just add the fragment?

Adding a fragment in the Activity that is initially launched causes the inflate error. This is how I was adding the fragment, using the following method

```
public void addFragment(int containerId, Fragment fragment) {
    // check if the fragment has been added already
    Fragment temp = mFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(fragment.getClass().getSimpleName());
    if (!Utils.checkIfNull(temp) && temp.isAdded()) {
        return;
    }

    // add fragment and transition with animation
    mFragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(containerId, fragment,
            fragment.getClass().getSimpleName()).addToBackStack(null).commit();
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: can you share full crash stack

Comment: I added the crash stack

Comment: check this `class="com.example.fragments.MainFragment"` it is correct or not?

Comment: view content that you are rendering in MainFragment is not correct  at line number 23.

Comment: @keyur9779 yes, that line is the setContent(layout) line. It happens because I removed the class="com.example.fragments.MainFragment" line from XML. My question is, how come this is required?

Comment: @Patel Pinkal that is correct. When that line is there everything works fine, but the lifecycle does not work properly. If that line is not there, I receive the error I posted

Comment: it is required bcz the view you are passing for rendering is not correct.

Comment: @keyur9779 Thank you. I made an update taking your advice and everything seems to be working now.

Comment: @portfoliobuilder Wellcome.